# Google Places Javascript Library with iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, google-places-api, google-places

I need to search for places nearby, so I could use the regular Google Places API with the https requests, but that gives my a limit per app instead of per user.

If my user base grows, I'm screwed... So instead Google said:

```
If you are developing a web based application that only needs to search for places,
and is not submitting new places or Place Bumps, you should use the Places library
of the Maps API rather than using the Places API web service. The Places library
assigns a quota to each end user rather than to each key. This means that your
available quota increases with your user base rather than being capped at a fixed
amount.
```

Therefore, I'd like to know how to use the Javascript library in my iOS app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rodrigo, did you get anywhere?